# How can I capture save/update/delete events of custom extension?

Tags: magento-1.7, event-observer

I have one custom extension installed, and I want to capture its save/update/delete action events and I am not sure how can I capture those events. Please help.

I have successfully able to capture those events for core modules like product and categories but not sure how can I perform the same for the custom extension.

I have tried adding `eventPrefix = 'aw_blog' on AW_Blog_Model_Blog class` and than in my config.xml file

```
 <aw_blog_prepare_save>
            <observers>
                <post>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>post/observer</class>
                    <method>blogBeforeSave</method>
                </post>
            </observers>
        </aw_blog_prepare_save>
```

but still its not working for me. Please help.
Thanks

Comment: you have to add mage dispatch event function in you save / update and delete action you can refer this blog link for it https://inchoo.net/magento/magento-event-driven-programming-tips-tricks/

Comment: @Himanshu thanks for the tip , but is it good practice to directly place dispatch event ? I mean in third party extension?

Comment: Yes why not!, because in the end it will be helpful in extending that data. or else you can catch magento's  `action controller` events if you don't want to add dispatch event.

Comment: Accept my answer if it would be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add mage dispatch event function in your save / update and delete action.

You can refer this blog link for it https://inchoo.net/magento/magento-event-driven-programming-tips-tricks/

OR

You can get magento's `action_controller_event`
If you don't want to add dispatch event

Hope this will be helpful.